# How to sync 2 remotes using Phabricator Diffusion

Tags: phabricator, git-workflow

I have to use 2 remotes for my repositories. For eg.

- One is my local git server (gitblit)
- One is Github/bitbucket

Additionally, I have to use Phabricator to manage all this. So the workflow i am thinking is:

I push the changes to my local git server, and my friends push to github. Phabricator Observe the changes from local git server + Github and sync it with the other remote changes. I have tried Mirror option, but it deleted the changes from one of remote, because that's what mirror is supposed to do.

So I need to know a way which i can use to sync these 2 remotes using Phabricator.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from creating a (read-only, as you discovered) mirror, Phabricator doesn't really have any ability to push to other servers.  It assumes one of the following workflows:

1. Phabricator is the master copy of the repository - everyone pushes to Phabricator (Phabricator can push to mirrors in this scenario).
2. Some other server is the master copy of the repository - Phabricator will monitor the remote master and keep a read-only copy of the repository locally.

It might be possible to implement a respository merging task in Harbormaster, but you'll have to be prepared for frequent manual intervention in any workflow that has users pushing to different repositories and expecting automation to sync them together.  Probably this syncing task would be easier if you were to get rid of the gitblit server from the equation, and just use Phabricator locally.